# HTML dynamic number of elements in a form with post

Tags: php, html

I have code that basically uploads a spreadsheet of data, could have 5 columns or 10 columns or whatever. Each column needs to have a drop down box specifying the data type, and the data types selected should be submitted via post with a form to another php site. How would I do this, this is the code that creates the elements.Is there a way to dynamically create elements, like delimist . attCount, and how would i put this loop into an html form to submit the data? Is there any way to put the values of all of these into an array for convince? Thanks.

EDIT: Ok thanks for the dynamic stuff, but how would i put this into a form and submit this via post to another page. Or is there another way to post information. I dont know much about php.

```
    while($attCount < count($attArray)) {
        echo "<select name=\"delimList\">";
        echo "<option value=1>tab</option>";
        echo "<option value=2>comma</option>";
        echo "<option value=3>semi-colon</option>";
        echo "<option value=4>ampersand</option>";
        echo "<option value=5>pipe</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        $attCount = $attCount + 1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a foreach loop and assigning the first index in your array will give you what you're expecting:

```
$options = [1=>'tab','comma','semi-colon','amperstand','pipe','another-value'];
echo "<select name=\"delimList[]\">\r\n";
foreach($options as $val => $option){
    echo "<option value=\"$val\">$option</option>\r\n";
}
echo "</select>\r\n";
```

output:

```
<select name="delimList[]">
<option value="1">tab</option>
<option value="2">comma</option>
<option value="3">semi-colon</option>
<option value="4">amperstand</option>
<option value="5">pipe</option>
<option value="6">another-value</option>
</select>
```

To sumbit the page you'll need to put everything inside of

```
<form method="post"> // you may want to add an action="..."
....                 // if you want to post to another page,
</form>              // instead of the same one
```

You'll also need a submit button too...

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

After submit you can check the values like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delimList'])){
    foreach($_POST['delimList'] as $key => $value){
        echo "delimList[$key] = $value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if i have 10 drop downs, this stores the values of each drop down in this array. So then where do the drop downs themsleves get made, in the code i already have? And how would i submit this data via post to anoher php page?

Comment: 1) Do all the dropdowns contain the same data? 2) yes 3) you need a form

Comment: Yes they do, the are all exactly the same, how would i make a form in this situation, PHP is heavily intermixed with the HTML here.

Comment: So ya, I have 10 differnt drop downs, that are all named delimList, how am i supposed to distingush between these with the post informatin.

Comment: You'll need to set the name on each `<select>` accordingly, such as delimList_product1, delimList_product2, ...

Comment: Alternatively, if your server-side language is php you can use echo "<select name=\"delimList[]\">\r\n";

Comment: And this is possible to do dynamically? This is seemingly a neccesity, like name = delimList . $counter, so i have delimList1, delimList2 etc. You can do this in some langauges, if this isnt doable in PHP not sure what i can do about this.

Comment: What would that do jeff, if i have 10 drop downs then the 10 chosen values will be in that delimList array?

Comment: nice jeff, didn't think of that

Comment: glad to help, don't forget to upvote/accept if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the value of all of these into an array… by putting all the values of these into an array!

```
$myArray = ['tab','comma','semi-colon','amperstand','pipe','another-value'];
echo '<select name="delimList">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {//Loop thru all
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$myArray[$i].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```